# How can I adapt an API that uses the post method to be used by Google Sheets?

Tags: jquery, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is code:

curl usage:

```
curl -v -H "Authorization: Basic Y2xpZW50ZTpjbGllbnRl" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"cnpjRemetente":60701190000104,"cnpjDestinatario":30539356867,"modal":"R","tipoFrete":"1", "cepOrigem":2323000,"cepDestino":7093090,"vlrMercadoria":100.00,"peso":50.55,"volumes":100}, "cubagem":[{"altura":0.46,"largura":0.67,"comprimento":0.67,"volumes":10}]' -X POST https://api.braspress.com/v1/cotacao/calcular/json
```

Jscript usage:

```
var authorizationBasic = 'Y2xpZW50ZTpjbGllbnRl';
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'https://api.braspress.com/v1/cotacao/calcular/json',
data: '{"cnpjRemetente":60701190000104,"cnpjDestinatario":30539356867,"modal":"R","tipoFrete":"1", "cepOrigem":2323000,"cepDestino":7093090,"vlrMercadoria":100.00,"peso":50.55,"volumes":10,"cubagem":[{"altura":0.46,"largura":0.67,"comprimento":0.67,"volumes":10}]}',
dataType: "json",
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
xhrFields: {
withCredentials: true
},
crossDomain: true,
headers: {
'Authorization': 'Basic ' + authorizationBasic,
},
success: function (result) {
console.log(result);
},
error: function (req, status, error) {
console.log(error);
}
```

Website that usaged: https://api.braspress.com/home

I got it on another site by the get method, but with this site it didn't work, here's the worksheet that I managed to do with:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fd9NSBGjHZd71tCGBGjgLfGiz_Zl8ZQ0-paxXYkL8pg/edit?gxid=-8203364

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- Your showing curl command and Javascript work fine.
- You want to convert these requests to Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and please set your value to `###` of `"Basic ###"`, and save the script. When you use this script on Spreadsheet, please put a custom function of `=myFunction()` to a cell. By this, the value is retrieved.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const url = "https://api.braspress.com/v1/cotacao/calcular/json";
  const data = { "cnpjRemetente": 60701190000104, "cnpjDestinatario": 30539356867, "modal": "R", "tipoFrete": "1", "cepOrigem": 2323000, "cepDestino": 7093090, "vlrMercadoria": 100.00, "peso": 50.55, "volumes": 10, "cubagem": [{ "altura": 0.46, "largura": 0.67, "comprimento": 0.67, "volumes": 10 }] };
  const params = {
    payload: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: { authorization: "Basic ###" } // Please set your value.
  }
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  const obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  return [keys, keys.map(k => obj[k])];
}
```

- When I saw your curl command, the data is incomplete. So, I used the data from your Javascript.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)